# Why does InkScape apparently produce incorrect SVG files, and how to fix it?

Tags: inkscape, svg

After making a logo in InkScape 1.0.1 (also tried with 1.0.2, the latest version), "Save as" optimized SVG, it produces an `.svg` file which renders in my browser but fails validation with the "v.Nu" HTML/CSS/SVG validator program.

This is the v.Nu error:

```
Attribute “aria-label” not allowed on element “g” at this point.
```

This is the offending line:

```
<g transform="matrix(blablabla)" fill="#fff" style="shape-inside:url(#rect869);white-space:pre" aria-label="?">
```

If I open the .svg file in a text editor and remove the  `aria-label="?"` part, it then passes validation. So it's specifically about that part...

I have searched all over the program and save dialogue box for some way to "disable aria-label" or similar, but there's just no such option.

It appears as if InkScape is producing invalid SVG files? Or is the v.Nu validator broken?

The same exact error happens even if I just "save as" a normal .svg, so it's not specifically related to using the "optimized" SVG format.

This is so annoying because I auto-validate all my HTML, CSS and SVG files before they are let through, and now it keeps breaking/failing all the time due to the (apparently) broken SVG saving in InkScape.